# ng-include is not including content.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently using 1.5.3 AngularJS Version & ng-include="'file.html'" is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>

        <!-- Include AngularJS Files -->
        <script src="vendor/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>

        <title>Website Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Include Content.html to index.html -->
        <header ng-include="'content.html'"></header>

    </body>
</html>
```

When i run this code it doesnt show anything on index.php

content.html exists with:

```
<h1>Hello, this is my website.</h1>
```

It will just not work.

my plunker code to see how i am doing it

plnkr.co/edit/OagoGf8AavIRxFgGVZSl

Comment: Is your path to content.html correct?  is it relative to your index.html?  Do you receive an error in the console?

Comment: Can you demonstrate us a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/)?

Comment: i will put it in plunker

Comment: ok i made it in plunker

Comment: code is : https://plnkr.co/edit/OagoGf8AavIRxFgGVZSl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have to use `angular.module` to have angular bootstrap your application to the dom. This is how angular starts.

The format is

`angular` to call angular,

`.module` to specify to angular which module you are looking for,

`('myapp'` the name of the module

`, [])` to specify any dependencies your app has. You can attach all sorts of stuff to your app which is extremely useful.

altogether, that's `angular.module('myApp', [])`

Note, you can hook into your app without re-bootstrapping at anytime with `angular.module('myApp')` without  the array of dependencies. This will retrieve your application without instantiating it. Then you can chain controllers, factories, whatever to it like this:

`angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {})`

It looks like you're coming from PHP, so you're in for a real treat once you start using angular. Good luck with your app!

Here, I edited your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fQnngC49d5QsHAzti7Nc

Comment: yea i came from php trying to learn javascript / AngularJs / Jquery / Ajax. Learning new languages

Comment: Well, good luck! Angular developers are in high demand right now, so you picked a good field.

Answer (score 2):

just take a look at console errors?

Plunker says that there is no module "myApp". So, you didn't include any `.js` files in plunker.

Actually I didn't know, is angular work right way without any `js`, but in normal case you should define the main app module and controllers for each page

Answer (score 2):

Angular isn't actually running on that page. Just including angular in your `<head>` isn't quite enough.

Here's what you've done so far:

1. Define an HTML file that pulls in the angular library.
2. Write HTML that tells the page that it should be using the angular module `myApp`.

What you need to do now is simply create that module. To so this, just create a javascript file with one line:

`angular.module('myApp', []);`

This creates an angular app called `myApp` on the global scope. Then add a `<script>` tag to include the new .js file in your `index.html`. That's it! Now Angular will look at you HTML file, see that you want the app `myApp` to run on the HTML, and it will find that app in your new JS file.

[Here's your plunkr updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwDNijqpgeecdxsqgn00?p=preview)

Hope this helps.